# Adaptive Median Filter

Tags: image-processing, filtering, matlab

I am constructing code for adaptive median filter . When i execute it it gives me error at line No 12. Not enough arguments. and on line 28.Unexpected MATLAB Expression.

```
 function f = adpmedian(g, Smax)


    %ADPMEDIAN Perform adaptive median filtering.

    %   F = ADPMEDIAN(G, SMAX) performs adaptive median filtering of

    %   image G.  The median filter starts at size 3-by-3 and iterates up   

    %   to size SMAX-by-SMAX. SMAX must be an odd integer greater than 1.

    % SMAX must be an odd, positive integer greater than 1.

      **12>>**if (Smax <= 1) || (Smax/2 == round(Smax/2)) || (Smax ~= round(Smax))
           error('SMAX must be an odd integer > 1.')
        end
        [M, N] = size(g);
        % Initial setup.
        f = g;
        f(:) = 0;
        alreadyProcessed = false(size(g));
        % Begin filtering.
        for k = 3:2:Smax
           zmin = ordfilt2(g, 1, ones(k, k), 'symmetric');
           zmax = ordfilt2(g, k * k, ones(k, k), 'symmetric');
           zmed = medfilt2(g, [k k], 'symmetric');
       `28>>`    processUsingLevelB = (zmed > zmin) & (zmax > zmed) & ...
               ~alreadyProcessed; 
           zB = (g > zmin) & (zmax > g);
           outputZxy  = processUsingLevelB & zB;
           outputZmed = processUsingLevelB & ~zB;
           f(outputZxy) = g(outputZxy);
           f(outputZmed) = zmed(outputZmed);
           alreadyProcessed = alreadyProcessed | processUsingLevelB;

           if all(alreadyProcessed(:))
              break;
           end

        end

    % Output zmed for any remaining unprocessed pixels. Note that this
    % zmed was computed using a window of size Smax-by-Smax, which is
    % the final value of k in the loop.
    f(~alreadyProcessed) = zmed(~alreadyProcessed);
```

Comment: is it possible that `sMax` is empty? why do you use `|` as "or", why not `||`?

Comment: See [logical operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/logical-operators.html) element-wise vs. "short circuit" types of operators.

Comment: With wath argument do you call that function? I would also suggest that you use `mod(Smax, 2) == 1` there instead of the rounding

Comment: @MuhammadUsman clearly `sMaxs` should not be empty, but is it possible that it is empty (for some reason) when you got the error? can you run in debug mode and verify that `sMax` is not empty?

Comment: I would like to report that if I use the code and execute: `r =adpmedian(1,3)` - I do not get any errors on matlab 2012b. Could it be that your matlab is not reloading the edited file?

Comment: Code seems fine, please provide a reproducible example including parameters.